# Save existing PdfDocument to file

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I'm currently trying to split a PDF file and then save each ne `PdfDocument` to a new file. The Problem is that I don't find any way to attach a new `PdfWriter` to an existing `PdfDocument`. This is the code I'm currently using to open and split the PDF file (just a mockup code example):

```
IList<int> splitByPage = new List<int>() { 1,2,3};
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(@"C:\temp\test.pdf"));
PdfSplitter splitter = new PdfSplitter(pdfDoc);
IList<PdfDocument> splittedDocuments = splitter.SplitByPageNumbers(splitByPage);
```

This is working and I have a set of `PdfDocument` objects. Now I want to save them to new files. I've found a solution in java, where it is possible to create a new instance of PdfWriter based on a given `Document` and an `OutputStream` but in .net I didn't find an equivalent to this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you take a look at the example on the Github repo? https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/develop/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/merge/MergeAndCount.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you need to extend how the [PdfSplitter](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_utils_1_1_pdf_splitter.html) class handles the documents, by creating a new [PdfWriter](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_writer.html) instance on the GetNextPdfWriter method.

```
public static readonly String DEST = "splitDocument1_{0}.pdf";


public void Split()
{
    IList<int> splitByPage = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(@"C:\temp\hello.pdf"));
    PdfSplitter splitter = new PdfSplitter(pdfDoc);
    IList<PdfDocument> splittedDocuments = new CustomPdfSplitter(pdfDoc, DEST).SplitByPageNumbers(splitByPage);

    foreach (PdfDocument doc in splittedDocuments)
    {
        doc.Close();
    }

    pdfDoc.Close();
}

private class CustomPdfSplitter : PdfSplitter
{
    private String dest;
    private int partNumber = 1;

    public CustomPdfSplitter(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String dest) : base(pdfDocument)
    {
        this.dest = dest;
    }

    protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
    {
        return new PdfWriter(String.Format(dest, partNumber++));
    }
}
```

I could not find online the documentation for GetNextPdfWriter, but here it is from [source code](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/0cf11041646cffaaea00132fab95bcd60aac1233/itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/utils/PdfSplitter.cs#L252):

```
/// <summary>This method is called when another split document is to be created.</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This method is called when another split document is to be created.
/// You can override this method and return your own
/// <see cref="T:iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter" />
/// depending on your needs.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="documentPageRange">the page range of the original document to be included in the document being created now.
/// </param>
/// <returns>the PdfWriter instance for the document which is being created.</returns>
protected internal virtual PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
```

Besides the example on [Github](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/develop/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/merge/MergeAndCount.cs), I could also find an example on the [Volume Counter FAQ](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/volume-counter-faq) (3rd example).